# mod_rewrite get current iteration

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I was wondering if there was any way to get the current iteration that mod_rewrite is on. For example, if I wanted to name a $_GET variable after this `iterator`:

```
RewriteCond {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+) $2?iterator=$1 [QSA]
```

Where `iterator` is the current loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.

You want to process a request like /process.ext/5 ? The $1 would be your iterator value already? What else do you want?

Comment: How will that solve any purpose in your code?

Comment: Say I have a pdf located in `"/var/www/data/pdf/$username$year$month.pdf"`. I want to give the user the impression that they are accessing "/var/www/example.com/year/month/report.pdf". I could do this with 3 matches: `RewriteRule ([\^]+)/([\^]+)/([\^]+) [L,QSA]` `RewriteRule ([\^]+)/([\^]+) [L,QSA]` `RewriteRule ([\^]+) [L,QSA]`. If I'm not mistaken, however, mod_rewrite loops until it cannot match any rules, so those three rules would be overkill. I'm thinking match, append query string, remove matched content, repeat. It would let me remove two lines and an `[L]` flag.

Comment: @ROunofF yeah, its that iterator value, but it's not the current iteration

Comment: With the current description of your problem. You only need one rule for that and no need to worry about the "iteration" in mod_rewrite. Try it or give more example or what you tried and what is causing issue :)

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /$1$2$3 [L]

PS: The L tells mod_rewrite to stop trying to match other rules and pass the url to the next handler (inside apache).

Comment: @ROunofF Ok, I revisited this one recently and came to the same conclusion. However, I didn't use the [L] flag. I instead had a rule that matched a pattern, grouping certain aspects of a URL, then processing those on the second run through. Once I get it perfect, I'll post it.